# How to send particular row data to previous view on select of row in current tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, object

I have a UIButton in the first view. When I click on a button I pushed a 2nd view having table view with data .i want the data of particular row selected by the user in 2nd view sent to the first view.In short second view row data on 1st view while selecting a row on poping to first view?please help .

thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to pass Data from one view to another depending on what cell the user presses? Are you using Storyboards in your app or .xib

Comment: no i am not using story board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use delegate to send data from selected row in 2nd view to the 1st view.
I wrote a tutorial on how to use delegates here: http://krodev.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/objective-c-delegates/.

When you setup a delegate, use 2nd view method to send selected row's data back to 1st view:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // row index
    int rowIndex = indexPath.row.
    // when you have row index you can get row data from your table view datasource 

    // if your data is NSString (method name depends on your implementation of delegate)
    [self.firstViewDelegate selectedRowsData:(NSString *)data];
    // return to the 1st view
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your help .i am getting value in 1st class but cant use that value in another function in that class .it showing null value inside another function in console while i am printing why so any suggestion..

Comment: You're welcome. Did you make instance variable for that value in the 1st class (in .h file of the 1st class add property for that value and synthesize it in .m file) and then assigned value you get in delegate method to that variable? Or maybe you released it before you used it again (if you are not using ARC).

Comment: i am not working in story board or i have already done with property and synthesized but it is showing null value while i am printing that value on button action in same class

Comment: It's really hard to guess without seeing any code. This are my guesses: if you aren't using ARC, value may not be retained and it is released when you exit delegate method; double check if delegate method is actually called and value is set; double check if you are sending nil from 2nd view or actual value;

Answer (score 0):

Go to your second view, In the method of your `UITableView`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Add the condition `if(indexPath.row == 0)` in which you would use a **global string** already declared in your `AppDelegate.m` file to pass data to your previous view using the `popViewController` method.

This string will be equal to your `cell.textLabel.text`.

Example

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
textString = cell.textLabel.text;
}
```

and so on for your various rows. Similarly you can add the textString to your cell of the first table in the 1'st view. Any doubt please tell. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   Your First View Controller.index = index path.row
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's best to include a little explanation or some links to help explain *why*.